# ADSI - Local disabled users list from multiple computers in a txt file

Tags: powershell, adsi

I am trying to use a text file for a list of computers to query and get a list of all active and disabled local accounts on each of them.

This part is working fine for a single computer (named **glm4453**):

```
([ADSI]('WinNT://glm4453' -f $env:COMPUTERNAME)).Children | Where { $_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user' } | ForEach {
$user = ([ADSI]$_.Path)
$lastLogin = $user.Properties.LastLogin.Value
$enabled = ($user.Properties.UserFlags.Value -band 0x2) -ne 0x2
if ($lastLogin -eq $null) {$lastLogin = 'Never'}

Write-Host
Write-Host Username: ( " " * 5 ) $user.name
Write-Host Last Login: ( " " * 3 ) $lastLogin
Write-Host Enabled: ( " " * 6 )  $enabled
}
```

By when I try to add a list of computers from a txt file, I get an empty output.

```
foreach ($name in (get-content C:\temp\computer.txt))
{

([ADSI]('WinNT://$name' -f $env:COMPUTERNAME)).Children | Where { $_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user' } | ForEach {
$user = ([ADSI]$_.Path)
$lastLogin = $user.Properties.LastLogin.Value
$enabled = ($user.Properties.UserFlags.Value -band 0x2) -ne 0x2
if ($lastLogin -eq $null) {$lastLogin = 'Never'}

Write-Host
Write-Host Username: ( " " * 5 ) $user.name
Write-Host Last Login: ( " " * 3 ) $lastLogin
Write-Host Enabled: ( " " * 6 )  $enabled
}}
```

Note that I am running Server 2008 which limits the PowerShell commands I can run.

Thanks in advance for any assistance provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PowerShell [-f Format operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html) is used to replace numbered placeholders in a string. These placeholders take the form of `{0}`, `{1}` etc and can be combined with extra formatting.

In your code `'WinNT://glm4453' -f $env:COMPUTERNAME` does nothing, because there is no placeholder to replace, so the string simply remains 'WinNT://glm4453'.

In the second code, the same thing happens, but in that case, since you are using **single-quotes**, the `$name` varable won't be expanded.

You need to remove `-f $env:COMPUTERNAME` because it is of no use there and also use **double-quotes**, so the name gets expanded.

Let's say the computername in `$name` is 'PC-01'.

using single-quotes, `'WinNT://$name'` will take the string literally.
using double-quotes, `"WinNT://$name"` will result in `WinNT://PC-01`

See [About Quoting Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules)

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your assistance and guidance in getting this working